# DjangoRestFramework again downloading lastest Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

i have python(3.6) and django(2.1.15) on PC .then i am trying to install latest djangorestframework but it install again latest django 3.X.so i want keep my django 2.1.15 and install djangorestframework

Comment: You can't. DRF 3.11 requires Django 2.2 or higher

Comment: @ArakkalAbu this is just not true, https://www.django-rest-framework.org/community/3.11-announcement/#django-rest-framework-311

Comment: Pin your Django version in requirements to lower one and do downgrade of Django to your desired version note 2.2 is a LTS release 2.1 is at end of support

Comment: oops. You are right. I was referring the wrong source, [DRF 3.12](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework#requirements)

Comment: @ArakkalAbu master branch got you :D, always check version related one https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/tree/3.11.0#requirements

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a requirements file.

Basically create a requirements.txt file at the root of your project with the contents

```
django==2.1.15
djangorestframework==3.11.0
```

Then run, `pip install -r requirements.txt` to install